# C# XNA Texture2D.SetData rectangle?

Tags: c#, xna

I have a very large texture and would like to set the pixel data of a specific part of it. I need it to be as fast as possible so is it possible to give SetData a rectangle of data instead of the entire texture data?

Comment: All SetData are inherently slow because they are unbatchable API calls (which means they require system calls).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434430.aspx). However, getting part of the texture compared to the whole thing is unlikely make a difference except maybe if the texture is huge.